# Saving a 1 bit black-and-white bitmap to a stream in WinRT

Tags: bitmap, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, win2d

I am using Win2D to allow users to paint with their finger on a 1 bit black and white bitmap in a Windows Universal app. When the user has accepted their changes I need to upload them to Azure blob storage, hopefully using the WinRT equivalent of the [UploadFromStreamAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn451737.aspx) method.

In the wider .Net Framework [System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx) includes the member `Format1bppIndexed`, ideal for storing one-bit bitmaps. But in WinRT [Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapPixelFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmappixelformat.aspx) only contains the values

- Unknown
- Rgba16
- Rgba8
- Bgra8

with the proviso (from [Windows.Graphics.Imaging.Bitmapencoder.SetPixelData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.setpixeldata(v=win.10).aspx)) that "setting a pixel format of Unknown will result in failure".

(N.B. I have the bitmap in my code as a Win2D [Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.CanvasBitmap](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasBitmap.htm).)

How do I save a 1 bit bitmap to stream in WinRT?